# assign a name for pic in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I have a /.pic in tikz, but I can not assign a name for that. I want to draw some block in the right of that pic. I have attached the figure which I want. Could you help me with how to solve that? thanks. Here is the figure I want https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw7Xh.jpg

````
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
{myTrapezium/.pic ={\draw [fill=magenta!50] (0,0) -- (0,\b) -- (\a,\c) -- (\a,-\c) -- (0,-\b) -- cycle ;
\coordinate (-center) at (\a/2,0);
\coordinate (-out) at (\a,0);},
block/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=2em, minimum width=2.1em, font = \Large},
dot/.style = {circle,fill, inner sep=0.01mm, fill=black!15, node contents={}},
  myArrows/.style={line width=2mm, red,-{Triangle[length=1.5mm,width=5mm]},shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt, }}

    \def\a{2}  % width of trapezium
    \def\b{.9} % small height of trapezium
    \def\c{2}  % tall height of trapezium

\begin{tikzpicture}
[node distance=1mm, % space between drawn parts
every node/.style={align=center},]
 \coordinate (start) at (-4.08,4.5);
 \node[block, below = 8cm of start] (Alpha) {$x$};
 \node[block, below = 2cm of Alpha] (zed) {$y$};
  \pic (left)[right=3cm of Alpha, rotate=180] {myTrapezium} ;
\node at (left-center) {a} ;
  \def\d{.9}
  \coordinate (u) at (\d,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the already provided `trapezium` shape?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, calc, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[trapezium, draw, minimum height=2cm, fill=magenta!50, shape border rotate=270] (a) {a};
    \draw ($(a.top left corner)!.2!(a.top right corner)$)--++(0:1cm) node[right, draw] {1};
    \draw ($(a.top left corner)!.8!(a.top right corner)$)--++(0:1cm) node[right, draw] {2};
    \draw ($(a.bottom left corner)!.2!(a.bottom right corner)$)--++(180:1cm) node[left, draw] {3};
    \draw ($(a.bottom left corner)!.8!(a.bottom right corner)$)--++(180:1cm) node[left, draw] {4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.